# Stringbuilder to Array to 2D Array causing NullPointerException JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, stringbuilder

I have a method reading a .txt file into a 2d Array, this txt file contains rows with a "Y" or "N" and a team number from 1-24 (Rows look like "T# Y" or "T# N", I then search that 2d Array for a specific element in the rows ("Y") and return how many rows had a "Y" and count for each team the number of true cases.

24 Teams, should be 24 rows in the 2d array atleast I thought!

```java
public static String[][] buildTimes(String[][] sub) {
    StringBuilder scores = new StringBuilder(sub.length);

    for (String[] row : sub) {
        scores.append(Arrays.stream(row)
                .filter(str -> str.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                .toArray().length);
        scores.append("/");
    }

    String[] tempArray = scores.toString().split("");
    String[][] finalTimes = new String[24][1];

    for (int i = 0; i < finalTimes.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < finalTimes[i].length; j++) {
            int index = 0;
            finalTimes[i][j] = tempArray[index];
            index++;
        }
    }
    return finalTimes;
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.lambda$buildTimes$0(test.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:550)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:517)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:523)
    at test.buildTimes(test.java:74)
    at run.main(run.java:10)
```

I have no clue why I am getting these errors, I am definitely inexperienced with StringBuilders, I also tried using an INT ArrayList and same errors.

Example of output:
Team 1   (Count of Y's Found for Team1)
Team 2   ("" for team2)
Team 3   ("" for team 3)

I just need a 2D Array holding Team# and "Y"'s found for each team in rows from file in Column 1 through 24.

Answer (score 1):

As long as Stream API is already used in the question, it is better to use its facilities to count the frequencies of elements using `Collectors::groupingBy` instead of `StringBuilder`.  If it is important to count frequency as `Integer`, `Collectors::summingInt` may be used instead of `Collectors::counting` returning `Long`.

And the final result returning a sparse array for each team (including those missing in the input file) can be generated using `IntStream::range` or `IntStream::rangeClosed`

The implementation can be as follows:

```java
public static String[][] countYesPerTeam(String[][] data) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(data)
            .filter(item -> item.length > 1 && "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(item[1]))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item[0], Collectors.summingInt(item -> 1)));
    
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 24)
                    .mapToObj(i -> new String[] {
                        "T" + i, 
                        Integer.toString(map.getOrDefault("T" + i, 0))
                    }) // provide [TN, yesCount] per team
                    .toArray(String[][]::new);
}
```

Test

```java
String[][] data = {{"T1", "Y"}, {"T2", "Y"}, {"T1", "N"}, {"T2", "Y"}, {"T4", "y"}};
String[][] stat = countYesPerTeam(data);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(stat));
```

Output:

```
[[T1, 1], [T2, 2], [T3, 0], [T4, 1], [T5, 0], [T6, 0], [T7, 0], [T8, 0], [T9, 0], [T10, 0], [T11, 0], [T12, 0], [T13, 0], [T14, 0], [T15, 0], [T16, 0], [T17, 0], [T18, 0], [T19, 0], [T20, 0], [T21, 0], [T22, 0], [T23, 0], [T24, 0]]
```

If team names are not needed in the resulting array, it may be created as:

```java
// ....
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 24)
                    .mapToObj(i -> new String[] {
                        Integer.toString(map.getOrDefault("T" + i, 0))
                    }) // provide [yesCount] per team
                    .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Comment: This just about works perfectly, I am just getting 0's however for each team score of Y's.

Comment: Can you provide a short example of 2D array fed into method `countYesPerTeams`?  Current implementation assumes that the each row has a format `{"Tx", "Y|N"}` where `Tx` is the team number in `row[0]` and `row[1]` contains `Y` or `N`.  This assumption was made out of the statement: _Rows look like "T# Y" or "T# N"_, so when a row is split by `" "`, the array in the mentioned format is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem in an easy way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] a = {{"T1", "Y"}, {"T1", "Y"}, {"T2", "N"}, {"T2", "Y"}};
    System.out.println(buildTimes(a)); // {T1=2, T2=1}
}

public static Map<String, Long> buildTimes(String[][] data){
    return Stream.of(data)
            .filter(item -> item.length > 1)
            .filter(item -> "y".equalsIgnoreCase(item[1]))
            .map(item -> item[0])
            .collect(groupingBy(item -> item, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Comment: The method groupingBy((<no type> item) -> {}, Collectors.counting()) is undefined for the type testJava(67108964), Just about works, just says that now however. I also need to move this data into a 2d array